# Как получить цвет ячейки в google-таблицах?

Tags: php, google-spreadsheet

Собственно вопрос в заголовке! Нашел кучу информации как в таблице установить цвет на ячейку, отформатировать ее, и тому подобное, но как прочитать нормально таблицу и получить информацию о форматировании ячейки никак найти не могу (((

вот что есть сейчас:

```
/**
 * Получение информации о таблице и листах
 *******************************************************/
// https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get
$response = $service->spreadsheets->get($spreadsheetId);


$response = $service->spreadsheets->get($spreadsheetId);
 
// Свойства таблицы
$spreadsheetProperties = $response->getProperties();
$spreadsheetProperties->title; // Название таблицы
 
 $response = $service->spreadsheets->get($spreadsheetId);

 // Получаем содержание ячеек таблицы
$range = 'Аркуш1';
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);

// TODO: Change code below to process the `response` object:
echo '<pre>', var_export($response, true), '</pre>', "\n";
```

И на этом застрял, третий день ищу инфу, найти толком ничего не могу!

**UP:** Решил задачу таким способом:

```
$colorb = file_get_contents("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/ИД таблицы?includeGridData=true&ranges=K12(это адрес ячейки)"&key=ключ API");
            
$obj = json_decode($colorb, true);

$red= $obj['sheets']['0']['data']['0']['rowData']['0']['values']['0']['userEnteredFormat']['backgroundColor']['red'];
$green= $obj['sheets']['0']['data']['0']['rowData']['0']['values']['0']['userEnteredFormat']['backgroundColor']['green'];
$blue= $obj['sheets']['0']['data']['0']['rowData']['0']['values']['0']['userEnteredFormat']['backgroundColor']['blue'];
```

Может, кому-то пригодится.

Comment: Решение вопроса лучше публиковать в виде ответа, а не в вопросе.

Comment: Почему бы не воспользоваться стандартным методом [Range.getBackgroundObject()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#getbackgroundobject) из арсенала Google Script ?